# Block bot/spider via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to block Baiduspider via htaccess but it still gets through.

Here's the full useragent of the Baiduspider that doesn't respect the robots.txt and isn't turned away by htaccess:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)
```

Here is what I have in robots.txt to try to block him (I know this one is most likely not the real Baiduspider and the impersonator won't respect robots.txt:

```
User-agent: Baiduspider 
Disallow: /
```

Here is what I have in htaccess to deal with him. Is there something incorrect in this or would someone suggest a better alternative?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I also tried this in htaccess and it still didn't solve it:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase user-agent "^Baiduspider" bad_bot 
<FilesMatch "(.*)">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: A RewriteCond on its own does nothing … you need to follow it by a RewriteRule if you want anything to happen.

Comment: Oh sorry the rule didn't get added. Here is what I have:

    `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider.* [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]`

Comment: `^` anchors a regex pattern to the beginning. The User Agent string you have shown does not _begin with_ `Baiduspider`.

Comment: So simply removing the ^ at the beginning of Baiduspider should fix it? (Sorry to belabor the point, but I'm new at this).